# In a given Range in Google Sheets, find the first empty row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am running an Apps Script, and some other program or users continually add entries/rows on the first 5 columns. The next 3 columns are contingent upon the values of the first 5, using some formulae fixed on the first non-header row. (The formulae are not necessarily mathematical, more like text processing, so I can't really use the Google Sheet function `ARRAYFORMULA` as much as I want to).

The way I want to do this is to get the latest rows (we call it `lastRow`). For the range covered by columns F:H (6-8), except the header row, I want to get the first empty row or the last non-empty row, to determine the exact region/range I need to update with the formulae.

[image: I need to find the range bounded by green box to update]

```
sh = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

let lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
let rangeOfInterest = sh.getRange(2, 6, lastRow, 3);

// how to get first empty row or last non-empty row of rangeOfInterest
```

Comment: `var Avals = ss.getRange("F1:F").getValues();
var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;` Assuming that `F,G,H` all have the same last row.

Comment: Doesn't append use the next empty row?

Comment: Arrayformula can do text processing.